# Cannot add plugins in vimrc

Tags: bash, vim, plugins, vim-plugin, dotfiles

Here is my vimrc

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

call plug#end()
```

I am getting this error ,

```
-bash: .vimrc: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: .vimrc: line 3: `call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')'
```

Couldn't figure why, any idea? Installed it from here https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug

Comment: Don't `source` your `~/.vimrc` file. It is for `vim` and not the shell.

Comment: oh ok , thanks , did'nt know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vimrc` is meant to be automatically sourced by Vim during startup and by nothing else. Sourcing it in your shell makes no sense whatsoever.